# Bind Kendo UI Grid change to other kendo component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid inside my component. I also have a Kendo switch in that component. I want the grid to refresh when the switch is toggled. The value from the switch will have an effect on the data used in the grid. How do I do that? The data for my grid comes from a DataBindingDirective. So, it looks something like this:

my-component.html

```
<kendo-switch [(ngModel)]='showDeleted' (click)="onShowDeleted($event)"> 
</kendo-switch>
<kendo-grid
       myDataBinding
...
...
></kendo-grid>
```

my-component.ts

```
 showDeleted = true;
 onShowDeleted(event): void {
    this.myService.showDeleted = this.showDeleted;
    // todo: force grid refresh
    }
```

MyDatabinding.ts ( extends DataBindingDirective)

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, grid: GridComponent) {
        super(grid);
    }

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.myService.subscribe((result) => {
        this.grid.data = result;
    });
this.rebind();
}

public rebind(): void {
        this.myService.query(this.state);
    }
```

MyService.ts (extends BehaviorSubject)

```
public query(state: any): void {
    this.fetch(state).subscribe(x => super.next(x));
  }

private fetch(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
//get data here
}
```

Comment: Is the value of the `kendo-switch` needed for your `DataBindingDirective` to work properly?

Comment: Show how you bind data for the first time.

Comment: Added clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your service is written. I will assume you were following tutorial [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/data-operations/data-binding/automatic-operations/#toc-custom-directives) (your service extends `extends DataBindingDirective`).

In this case this should work:

```
<kendo-switch [(ngModel)]='showDeleted' (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)"></kendo-switch>

onValueChange(event): void {
    this.rebind();
}
```

I am not sure what you mean with statement

> The value from the switch will have an effect on the data used in the
>   grid.

If you want to manipulate data on client you can do that in `subscribe` method.

**Edited after clarification (@BradL.)**

That is entirely new story. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/i5K2EvfeNNF1fw8ADoUz?p=preview) is a working plunkr. Open developers tools, change switch value and observe console window.

Critical parts:

```
//remote-binding.directive:
@Input() myFilter = false;

public rebind(): void {
        console.log("Grid will be refreshed. Switch value is: ", this.myFilter);
        this.products.query(this.state);
    }

//app.component.ts:
        <kendo-switch [(ngModel)]="checked" (valueChange)="onValueChange()"></kendo-switch>

        <kendo-grid
            productsBinding
            [myFilter]="checked"         //<-----------

  @ViewChild(ProductsBindingDirective) dataBinding: DataBindingDirective;

  public onValueChange()
  {
    window.setTimeout(()=>this.dataBinding.rebind());

  }
```

Comment: Added more clarification about how our component, service and grid interact. The onValueChange method would be inside my component class which doesn't extend DataBindingDirective.  When the switch is toggled, I need to update the data of the grid. That data will be different based on the switch state. Hope that makes is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just wondering, what is the purpose of the window.setTimeout around the rebind?

Comment: You need to wait that myFilter is bind to new value. Otherwise you will have previous value. Try it and observe console. When you will switch to true, console (`remote-binding.directive`) will report false, and when the next value will be changed (switch to false), you will get in console true.